# Is it possible to display segment of the UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have `UIImage` with some rounded shape. Is it possible to display somehow some sector of this UIImage. For example only the region from 0 degrees to 45 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, but you would have to use Core-Graphics and render the image again.

Check out [this tutorial](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/)